# Angular routing redirect to home when refresh another page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, router

In my application I have an homepage after the user logged in and some other pages. The problem is that when I am inside in one of these other pages and I refresh the page it sends me to home again. This is my `Routes`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent 
  },{
    path: 'list',  component: ListComponent, canActivate : [AuthGuardService]
  },{
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate : [AuthGuardService]
  },{
    path: 'detail/:id',  component: HomeComponent, canActivate : [AuthGuardService],
  },{
    path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' ,pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

the app-component has the router outlet

```
<div [ngClass]="{'container': (isLoggedIn$ | async), 'mt-2': (isLoggedIn$ | async)}" class="h-100">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

So, what I expect? First of all, if I am i "list" page (`localhost:4200/list`) and I refresh this page, it should be stay there. In that page. But now it redirects me to `localhost:4200/home`.
Of course, when I click a list item it should send me to `localhost:4200/detail/itemId` but it sends me always to home. Thanks

Edit with AuthGuardService:

```
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private route : Router, private store: Store<AppState>) {}

  canActivate() {
    return this.store
      .pipe(
          select(isLoggedIn),
          tap(loggedIn => {
              if (!loggedIn) {
                this.route.navigate(['login']);
              }
          })
      )  
  }
}
```

I add the login effect

```
login$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$
            .pipe(
                ofType(userActions.login),
                tap(action => {
                    localStorage.setItem('userInfo',
                    JSON.stringify(action.user))
                    this.router.navigate(['home']);
                })
            )
    ,{dispatch: false});
```

SOLUTION:

Well, after some hours of debugging I found the solution. basically I removed this.router.navigate(['home']); in the AuthGuardService and I put it on login function of the component as soon as the user is logged in. Put the this.router.navigate(['home']); in the AuthGuardService fires the guard everytime I refresh the page and so everytime it redirect me at home. That's it. Thanks

Comment: can you add `authGuardService` code

Comment: @programoholic sure, done

Comment: I think you should replace `' '` path in the bottom

Comment: Do you mean in the Routes?

Comment: What I am feeling in your `authGurd` you are checking some state which is getting removed on refresh.  check carefully there

Comment: Could be the problem? I just added the effect

Comment: authGuard canActivate method return a boolean/urltree/observable of boolean. So after checking is not loggedIn return false within that condition or return True

Comment: So, do you think I have to change something in my code? Because I don't know what I could change here

Comment: I created a STACKBLITZ (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aaokz3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with mock guard and it works properly. (you can change login state under login tab -> clikk on checkbox, guarded route in my example is LIST). Thus, it means that your guard probably returns FALSE. You are welcome to fork and change my STACKBLITZ, to reproduce your issue, ant then I will try to help

Comment: @Atlas91 did you ever firgure this out? Same problem in my very new Angular project with 2 routes. `''` and `anything-else` redirects to `''`. So strange.

Answer (score 1):

The order of routes is important because the Router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes.

- List routes with a static path first
- Followed by an empty path route, which matches the default route.
- The wildcard route comes last because it matches every URL.

The Router selects it only if no other routes match first.

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/router#route-order

So you change the order as follows

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent 
  },{
    path: 'list',  component: ListComponent, canActivate : [AuthGuardService]
  },{
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate : [AuthGuardService]
  },{
    path: 'detail/:id',  component: HomeComponent, canActivate :  [AuthGuardService],
  }
  {
    path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  ,{
    path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' ,pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

Comment: That's a good point to start and of course a good tip, thanks. Anyways that's not solve the problem. Probabily there's somehting wrong with my guard and how I read the state. Could be the problem?

Comment: authGuard canActivate method return a boolean/urltree/observable of boolean. 
So after checking is not loggedIn return false within that condition or return True

Answer (score -1):

I see you solved your issue but wanted to report what happened to me as it devoured a couple days of mine. In my case we wanted a particular route to open in a new tab unlike other routes.

```
<a *ngIf=link.externalRoute href={{link.route}} target="_blank">
```

It kept opening the new tab at the home route. I checked out my routing, authentication, auth guards, manual navigations in the code, couldn't find anything.

Turned out my route name was wrong. I had **'target-route'** but should have had **'#/target-route'**! The missing hash symbol had made the route invalid so it was falling back to the default route.

Of course this only helps if you happen to be using hash in your Angular routing, but maybe this will help someone someday.